# symfony 3.1 testing Bundle fails with Undefined index: kernel

Tags: phpunit, symfony-3.1, simple-phpunit

Symfony3 Unitests fails with the following error
Undefined index: kernel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php">

    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" />
        <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
        <env name="DEFAULT_DB_DRIVER" value="pdo_mysql" />
        <env name="DEFAULT_DB_HOST" value="mysql" />
        <env name="DEFAULT_DB_NAME" value="db" />
        <env name="DEFAULT_DB_USER" value="db" />
        <env name="DEFAULT_DB_PASSWORD" value="db" />
        <env name="MAIL_ENCRYPTION" value="ssl" />
        <env name="MAIL_PORT" value="587" />
        <env name="MAIL_SERVER" value="localhost" />
        <env name="MAIL_USER" value="root" />
        <env name="MAIL_PASSWORD" value="root" />
        <env name="DEFAULT_DB_PORT" value="3306" />
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
        <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
        <!-- define your env variables for the test env here -->
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="AmazonAPI Tests">
            <directory>src/ProductInterfaceBundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\CoverageListener">
            <arguments>
                <null/>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
            </arguments>
        </listener>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener">
            <arguments>
                <array>
                    <element key="time-sensitive"><string>Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation</string></element>
                </array>
            </arguments>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

and hier is my test class

```
use Namespace\ProductInterfaceBundle\Command\AmazonCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class AmazonCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{

    public function testExecute()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $application = new Application(self::$kernel);

        $application->add(new AmazonCommand());

        $command = $application->find('vendor:amazon:submit
');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(array(
            'command'  => $command->getName(),

            // pass arguments to the helper
            'username' => 'Wouter',
        ));

        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        $this->assertContains('Username: Wouter', $output);
    }

}
```

What I'm missing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to share more of you code: Where exactly is this errormessage  thrown and what happens at this line?

Seems like there is an uninitialized array with the "kernel" key missing. But without code: I have no idea. So I guess: More code needed :-)

btw: You shall update your Symfony (I think 6.0 is latest) and PHPUnit (I think version 9.5 is latest)

Comment: Thanks for Feedback, to update Symfony is out question because that needs lot of refactorings